# Has anyone got ubuntu working on a PC tablet?

Tags: acer, tablet, touchscreen

I tried 12.10 and my Acer Iconia W700 was unusable, so I gave up and waited for 13.04 and it is unusable again. I can get tips when I click in the left toolbar thing and I managed to start Firefox, but that is it. I can't get into settings. This is way more jarring than Windows 8. I really hoped Ubuntu would save me from Windows 8, but it seems like a total fail.

Edges do nothing. The UI is unresponsive apart from hints and being able to drag boxes on the desktop. How can I get Ubuntu working on this tablet?

Comment: You seem to be confusing 2 things here, 1-Ubuntu for the PC and 2-Ubuntu for Phones/Tablets. The first is *not* specially made for touchscreens, sure it works but you're to use it with a keyboard and a mouse, the second is a yet-to-be-released version of Ubuntu (available for testing on selected devices) that **is** for touchscreens.

Answer (score 0):

An Intel-based tablet (Core i5, 11.6", .95Kg, cooling fan).

This will probably be a great platform for ***Ubuntu desktop*** with touch interface someday.

However that is not where the market is focused ..

---

Have you tried out *Ubuntu Touch 13.04* on an **ASUS/Google Nexus 7** (or the larger Nexus 10)?

[image: Ubuntu Touch]

This is excellent work-in-progress, but its not about the full *desktop experience* on a smartphone or tablet.

Its about *mobility* ..

[Google Nexus 7 tablet .. to be Ubuntu’s ‘reference’ device](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/10/ubuntu-installer-for-nexus-7-tablet-made-available-for-devs)

[Ubuntu Touch - Project page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch) | 
[How to Install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) | 
[Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/ReleaseNotes)